# Data from javascript code insert to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, database

Here I have a script which help me to get places from google places API. So now I want to store all this into mysql but how? I'm new to mysql and php, and how to store data that I get from google places to database?

What I need to do here? Can someone show me on my example...

How to combine php and javascript;

CODE: http://jsbin.com/AlEVaCa/1

So I need to store data which I got from google:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var contentStr = '<h5>'+place.name+'</h5><p>'+place.formatted_address;
            if (!!place.formatted_phone_number) contentStr += '<br>'+place.formatted_phone_number;
            if (!!place.website) contentStr += '<br><a target="_blank" href="'+place.website+'">'+place.website+'</a>';
            contentStr += '<br>'+place.types+'</p>';
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          } else { 
            var contentStr = "<h5>No Result, status="+status+"</h5>";
            infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          }
        });

    });
```

I want to store all place.name,website ... etc. data to mydatabase. How to do that?
Is there any way to store this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX to send data to PHP file.

Use jQuery $.post()-AJAX method to send data to php file

```
 data = "name="+name+"&place="+website;
 $.post('file_to_store.php', data, function(data) {
     //Here you can get the output from PHP file which is (data) here
 });
```

Pure javascript way

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }

   data = "name="+name+"&place="+website;
   xmlhttp.open("POST","file_to_store.php",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

In file_to_store.php receive all data from $_POST[] global array

```
 if(isset($_POST)){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $website = $_POST['website'];
   //Do same for all other variables

   //Steps to insert Data into Database
   //1. Connect to database 
   //2. Select Database
   //3. Generate Database Insert Query
   //4. Run mysql Query to insert

   // Return appropriate return back to Javascript code - Success or Failure 
 }
```

Comment: yes bt how to make a loop here to put data to mysql: http://jsbin.com/AlEVaCa/3/edit

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablename (Place, Name, Website)
VALUES ('USA', 'Marco Jordan',35)"); mysqli_close($con);

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize($data)` then put it into database, use `unserialize()` after getting data from db.

Addition: this will store raw data, you'll probably need a parser also.

Addition 2: sorry I assumed that you got an array.

Alternative solution if you got non-array data:
you can use `base64_encode($raw_data)` to store and `base64_decode($encoded_data)` to use the encoded data coming from SQL.

Comment: i assumed that you've already got raw data from google. are you asking retrieving data from google?

Comment: can you post a raw data example please?

Comment: i only can see a map here, give me text data

Comment: click on submit and you will get a data

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your JavaScript program, executing on the *client* side, does not have direct access to the SQL database on the *host.*  You must use AJAX to issue requests to the host, and the host-side software must be programmed to handle them.  *Lots(!)* of existing tutorials on this subject are already out there ... everywhere.